# Laravel middleware detected but not executed

Tags: laravel, middleware, laravel-middleware

I have a middleware which **works fine when defined as a global middleware** in Kernel.php. However, I want it to be applied only to specific routes, so I do this:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'myapi/', 'middleware' => 'api'], function(){

});
```

Calling `php artisan route:list` shows that the middleware is detected correctly. However, it does not get executed (I know this because even purposely placing an error in the file does not do anything).

```
...
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    ...
    'api' => [
        'throttle:60,1',
        \App\Http\Middleware\CORSMiddleware::class,
    ],
];
```

When the middleware is set as global, it does not get listed by `route:list`. Also, purposely specifying a wrong middleware name in routes.php does not throw any error.

EDIT:
Logging shows that the middleware is executed for all GET ressource routes, but not for POST/PUT/DELETE.

Answer (score 0):

I believe middleware has to be placed inside an array when adding it to a group - that will cause it to trigger and give you the expected result:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'myapi/', 'middleware' => ['api']], function(){

});
```

Comment: Both syntaxes are allowed, otherwise artisan would not list the middleware in the `route:list`. But still even with that syntax it does not work :(